# What pattern do I use for interdependent class

Tags: oop, design-patterns, chess

I have read from other sources that it isn't a good idea for objects to know about each other especially the ones on same level. It should be more like hierarchy.

My problem is quite unique as I haven't figured out a way around it. Also I have been unlucky to come across any topic that addresses my issue specifically.

*The problem*
I am building a chess app and I am constructing the model of the app. Right now I have an abstract objects like for example `Piece` which other pieces like `Queen`, `Knight` and the rest would inherit from.
I also have a `Board` class which handles all board model and state of a game. Now each of my piece has a `generateMove()` method to calculate possible moves from their position and to do this they need to know the state of the board. Also the Pieces are been instantiated by Board at startup.

Question
Do I go ahead and instantiate Pieces by e.g

```
public class ChessBoard{
   Boardbit = 64bit
   Knight = new Knight(start_position, this) 

  //calculate

}
```

and then in Knight class method

```
public long generateMove(ChessBoard);
```

If no, what other ways can I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making `Chessboard` to know the `Knight` and vise versa is not elegant. I agree with you in this point. Kind of sticking with  the 'Tell don't ask' rule forces the 'higher level' element, in this case the chessboard, to tell the piece to move while providing all the required information. The `Chessboard` itself doesn't know which piece is moving (in this case of predicting possible moves for all pieces), but for sure never knows any details about how a piece can move or is allowed to move. This is just one possible solution using sort of Strategy Pattern. (The Visitor or some similar pattern could also be used here):

```
Main() {
    chessboard = new Chessboard()
    PiecesCollection = new PiecesCollection(new Knight(KnightStrategy, Color.Black))
    chessboard.AddPieces(PiecesCollection)

    CollectionOfAllPossibleMoveCollections = chessBoard.CallculateAllPossibleMoves()

    Move selectedMove = ShowOrSelectMove(CollectionOfAllPossibleMoveCollections)
    chessboard.ExecuteMove(selectedMove)
}

public class Chessboard{
   // fields
   PiecesCollectionWhite
   // where 'PiecesCollectionWhite' is a collection of `Piece`

   PiecesCollectionBlack
   // where 'PiecesCollectionBlack' is a collection of `Piece`

   CurrentlyVisitedPositionsCollection
   // where 'CurrentlyVisitedPositionsCollection' is a collection of `Position`

   // methods
   AddPieces(PiecesCollection, Color)

   CallculateAllPossibleMoves(Color) {
     CollectionOfPossibleMoveCollections = 
         FOREACH Piece IN PiecesCollection OF Color
             DO Piece.CalculateMoves(this.CurrentlyVisitedPositionsCollection)
     return CollectionOfAllPossibleMoveCollections // where 'CollectionOfAllPossibleMoveCollections ' is a collection that holds a collection of `Move` of which each nested collection represents the possible moves of a chess piece.
   }

   ExecuteMove(Move) {
       RemovePieceFromBoardIfNecessary(Move.ToPosition)
   }
} 

public class Piece 
{
   // fields
   Strategy
   Position
   Color

   // methods
   CallculateMoves(CurrentlyVisitedPositionsCollection) {
       PossibleMovesCollection = this.Strategy.Execute(CurrentlyVisitedPositionsCollection, this.Position)
       return PossibleMovesCollection where `PossibleMovesCollection` is a collection of `Move`
   }
}

public class Knight extends Piece
{
   ctor(Strategy, Color)
}

public class Stragtegy
{
  abstract Execute(currentPosition, allPiecesPositions) : PossibleMovesCollection 
}

public class KnightStrategy extends Strategy
{
  Execute(currentPosition, allPiecesPositions) {
      PossibleMovesCollection = ApplyKnightMoveAlgorithm()
      return PossibleMovesCollection 
  }

  private ApplyKnightMoveAlgorithm() : PossibleMovesCollection 
}

public class Move
{
  Position fromPosition
  Position toPosition
}

public class Color
{
  Black
  White
}

public class Position
{
  Color
  xCoordinate
  yCoordinate
}
```

This is just a sketch and not a complete example. There is some state information or operations missing. E.g. maybe you would have to store the `Color` that was moved last on the chessboard.

Since the `Chessboard` returns all possible moves (information about all currently visited coordinates) you can easily enhance the algorithm by implementing some intelligence to predict the best possible moves from this information. So before the controller or in this case the `Main()` will call `Chessboard.ExecuteMove(Move)` it could make a call to `PredictionEngine.PredictBestMove(CollectionOfAllPossibleMoveCollections)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, your generate all possible move function seem insightful but as you know I will like to ask what *this.currentlyVisitedPositionsCollection* type is.

Comment: this will be important because if checks are on the board is also needed to make valid moves. will the info be includes.

Comment: Also the bit Representation of same color would be needed so that pieces wouldn't jump to their own square.

Comment: I was trying to say that the chess board stores the coordinates of all pieces. The `ChessBoard`then passes this information to the strategy algorithm so that the `Strategy` can know which fields are visited by the own or the opponent colors.

Comment: Yes you are right. I know. This are details you have to implement in the e.g. `KnightStrategy` class. Like checking if the field is visited by your ow pieces. So yes when actually implementing this suggestion you would have to add a `Color`attribute to the `Position` class

Comment: The controller (the Main() in this case) that is operating the `ChessBoard` would then call `ChessBoard.ExecuteMove()` which would then check if the target coordinate is visited by an opponent color. If this is the case the controller can remove this piece from the board

Comment: This means I have to create a new object type like *Boardinfo* which will carry such information.

Comment: Before I mark this, I like to know why you have two Move classes?

Comment: No not necessary. The `CheckBoard` already has the attribute `CurrentlyVisitedPositionsCollection`. You would just need to populate the collection with the updated coordinates of all pieces by adding the corresponding instances of `Position`

Comment: Yes you are right. I am sorry for this copy and paste error. It's supposed to be a color class. I corrected it. I also added a class `Position` to the scheme as well to to sketch how it could look like

Comment: To your previous comment, that is why I was trying to be clear about what object type is *CurrentlyVisitedPositionsCollections*

Comment: Yes, no problem. It's a collection of type `Position`

Answer (score 1):

Much better is to have method `generateMove(boardState)`, so your Board should call whatever piece you have and pass them the necessary information for such task. It can be used even for some optimization as board can pregenerate some good-to-use structure each round only once and then pass it to all the pieces (like some 2d array).